# Android tablet screen size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen

I need to develop android application ONLY for android tablet 10.1.

For that can I created my xml file in my `res--->layout folder` for 10.1 tablet size?

Or do I have to create `res--->layout-large folder` for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the existing layout folder since you don't want to support any other screen sizes. Although you have to specify that in the AndroidManifest under the  tag

e.g. :

```
 <supports-screens android:resizeable="false"
                  android:smallScreens="false"
                  android:normalScreens="false"
                  android:largeScreens="true"                  
                  />
```

Comment: I do not have any android testing devices.can I test with this my Android emulator?

Comment: yes you can, you can download the motorola XOOM2 AVD from eclipse. It has a screen size of 10.1

Comment: can you please give me a link

Comment: open your android SDK manager, under Android 3.2(API 13)you will find XOOM2. Select the checkbox next to it and click install packages.

Answer (score 1):

EddyK's answer is correct if you only want your app to show up in the market for 10" tablets. if you want to provide 10"-tablet specific resources, you can qualify the respective resource folders with the `-sw700dp` qualifier.

```
layout-sw700dp
values-sw700dp
```

etc. use these in favor of the `-large`, `-normal`, etc. qualifiers (on Android 3.2+).

see [Declaring Tablet Layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts) on the Android developer site for details.

Answer (score 1):

```
Kindly Use This qualifier for your Android Project with compatible screen size.

Resource          Screen Size 

layout-small       <3 inch

layout-normal      3-4 inch

layout-large       >4 inch<7.1

layout-xlarge      7.1 - 10.1 inch
```

Comment: .Here I need to develop only for 10.1. when I design xml file in ONLY layout-large it gives me error.Eddy K gives me a what I'm looking answer.anyway I got what you saying also.Thanks for answer

Comment: use layout-xlarge instead od layout-large.

Comment: if I used layout-xlarge  xml file without normal layout folder xml files,does it run without errors?

Comment: yes it should be run without any error.If you are not declear layout-xlarge & still using only  layout-normal then also your 10.1 tablet taking layout form layout-normal.

Comment: if we declare all layout, I mean small, normal,large etc ,do we have to declare it in our manifest file ??

Comment: no if you want restricted your app when user download your application from google play then use mainfest file.